# Showing hidden files by default in file browser except home directory

Tags: files, xfce, cinnamon, nemo, thunar

I have pretty much the same question as [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061280/how-do-i-show-hidden-files-just-for-some-directories) but not for Ubuntu - for Cinnamon and Xfce Mint and MX (though of course an answer that is valid for many distros / GUIs would be especially helpful for more people).

I'm familiar with ctrl+H and alt+. but I'd prefer not to keep toggling and have helpful defaults. I generally **do** want to see hidden files but there are SO many hidden directories (and files) in home that it becomes really cluttered.

Comment: Cinnamon or Xfce? They are mutually exclusive. But the main issue is what file browser do you use since this will have to be a setting there. Is this about nemo or about thunar? Or maybe some other file browser?

Comment: I'm running more than one distribution across several systems. The best answer would address all (if that's even possible) and an acceptable answer would address any. Default file managers (in line with the tags).

Comment: Each file manager will have its own method or none, I really doubt you will find a one-size-fits-all answer. Have you searched for ways for each file manager you use? Which one is used by default on which platform? I personally never use file managers, and I suspect I'm not alone given the audience of this site (they're so much harder to use than the command line for most things) so the more detail you add to your question, the better your chances of someone being able to answer.

Comment: See [Can we set Nemo or Nautilus, to show hidden files per directory?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053550), https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2266, https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3189. I just ran a quick search for ["directory-specific hidden file settings nemo"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=directory-specific+hidden+file+settings+nemo&t=brave&atb=v320-1&ia=web) and there seem to be some useful hits there.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did see the "Ignore per-folder view preferences" in Nemo but that's really the opposite of what I want and it's unselected by default so I think that's the way I want it. It does suggest there's some per-folder preferences somewhere but I can't see them.

Comment: And I wasn't really expecting a one-size-fits-all. I've seen many answers on Stack Exchange sites that answer several closely-related questions in one. There's potential here for a bullet-point answer that helps people using (for example) whatever the LXQt file manager is. Even where GUI options aren't visible there can be command-line solutions that change GUI behaviour (e.g. this handy unrelated article https://alexcabal.com/disabling-gnomes-recently-used-file-list-the-better-way).

Comment: Yeah, but this is too broad. Yes, you want the same behavior, but you want it from completely different programs which are developed by different people for different environments so the questions aren't really closely related. Anyway, I haven't closed it, it's up to the community.

Comment: Well some of the "gsettings" stuff applies across Gnome, Cinnamon, Xfce and probably others too (I guess all GTK-based GUIs?). But maybe gsettings doesn't tie into file managers (I'm certainly no expert on it).